# How many flops do we need to find the inverse of $n*n$ matrix A using Cholesky factorization and forward and backward substitution.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

How many flops do we need to find the inverse of a positive definite $n*n$ matrix A using Cholesky factorization and forward and backward substitution.

I know that the cost of Cholesky factorization is approximately $\frac{n^3}{3}$ and solving one of the n equations $AX_1=e_1$ using forward and backward substitution is approximately $n^2$. However since $e_1$ is very sparse does that affect the number of flops required. Is it correct to assume that the total cost of solving for the inverse of A is $\frac{n^3}{3}+2n^3$?

Comment: [You mean](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS378/2011sp/lectures/chol4.pdf) $$\frac{1}{3}n^3 + 2n^3$$ ?

Comment: Also $2n^3$ because $n(n^2)$ for forward and $n(n^2)$ for backward?

Comment: @BCLC. edited. Also $2n^3$ because $n(n^2)$ for forward and  $n(n^2)$  for backward? -Yes.